# Is feature complementarity different from feature interaction?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, interaction, feature-selection, predictor

I am writing a conference paper in which I have a sentence like "**...`complementary`/`interactive` features...**". This sentence discusses features in the context of **feature selection** as a preprocessing step to solve a **classification problem**. However, given my little background in the field, I am not really sure if the two words do in fact refer to the same thing!

Can complementary features also be described as interactive ones, and vice versa? OR are "feature complementarity" and "feature interaction" totally different things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you talk about information-theoretic based feature selection... yes variable complementarity and interaction information are equivalent (at least in absolute value... the sign differ sometimes, depending on authors).